# Java inputstreamreader parse to int then reverse array and print as formatted string

Tags: java, arrays

The input is from a `InputStreamReader`. First input needs to be converted from `String` to `int` and will be the array `length`. Second input will be a `String` of space separated numbers, they need to be converted from `String` to `int`, put into an `int` array, reversed then printed as a space and comma separated `String`.

An example would be, if the user entered `3` as the initial input, that should set the array `length` to `[3]`. The second input of `1 2 3`.

Would be returned as

```
3 2 1
```

I have put some System outs to check what is being returned but I get `I@` errors.

If anyone can point out where I am going or which bit I need to look at in more detail, it would be really appreciated.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        String line;
        String stNew;

         BufferedReader inp = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        // first input which sets array length
        line = inp.readLine();
        stNew = inp.readLine();

        //first input as array size and create array
        int iArrayLength = Integer.parseInt(line);
        int[] list = new int[iArrayLength];

    //  System.out.println(list + " list[] ");

        //second input to populate array
        String[] stArray = stNew.split(" ");

    //  System.out.println(stArray + " stArray[]")

        for (int i = 0; i < iArrayLength; i++ ){
            list[i] = Integer.parseInt(stArray[i]);
        }

    //  System.out.println(list + " list[] ");

        while (stArray.length != iArrayLength) {
            System.out.println("Please input " + iArrayLength + " integers");

            for (int i = 0; i < iArrayLength; i++) {
                list[i] = Integer.parseInt(stArray[i]);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < list.length / 2; i++) {
                int temp = list[i];
                list[i] = list[list.length - 1 - i];
                list[list.length - 1 - i] = temp;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: What issues did you run into? I see only description of an assignment.

Comment: I get a I@ error with a few numbers after the @

Comment: Add a sample input with expected output - this is very unclear.

Comment: Add sample input + expected output, really unclear what is the problem.

Comment: `while (stArray.length != iArrayLength)` is it an infinite loop here?

Comment: Yes, of course. Apologies. I’ll add it to the main content

Comment: Don't forget to upvote useful answers and accept them if they solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

These messages are not errors, this is how an `Object` printed by default in Java.

An `array` is an `Object` and doesn't define any `@toString` method. It uses inherited method from `Object` class:

```
/**
 * Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
 * {@code toString} method returns a string that
 * "textually represents" this object. The result should
 * be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a
 * person to read.
 * It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.
 * ...
 * @return  a string representation of the object.
 */
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

From the code above you can see that the default array will be printed as class name + `@` + the hash code.

And if you'll try to get a class name of an array like you'll see `[I`:

```
System.out.println(a.getClass().getName());
```

what fully corresponds to the implementation of `toString()`.

To pretty-print the array use:

```
Arrays.toString(list);
```

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
    System.out.println(a.getClass().getName());
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

Output:

```
[I
[I@56cbfb61
[1, 2, 3]
```

Furthermore, you have an infinite loop at the line

```
while (stArray.length != iArrayLength)
```

The program will never end if enters this block of code.